# Skip Columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**problem**

I have first concatenating all data from the available excel files into a single dataframe and then writing that dataframe into a new excel file. However, I would like to do 2 simple things:

**a** leave a 2columns blank for each new dataframe that will be appended

**b** the headers and the bold formatting has disappeared after appending the dataframes. see a pic of how one excelFile initially looked [Original formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66C3w.png)

**attempt**   This is my attempt [Two Seperate DataFrames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzW7a.png)

```
data = []
for excel_file in excel_files:
    print(excel_file) # the name for the dataframe
    data.append(pd.read_excel(excel_file, engine="openpyxl"))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DVT', 'Col2', 'Col3']) #blank df maybe?!this line is not imp!
    #df1.style.set_properties(subset=['DVT'], {'font-weight:bold'}) !this line is not imp!
# concatenate dataframes horizontally
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
# save combined data to excel
df.to_excel(excelAutoNamed, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel available right now, so I can't test, but something like this might be a good approach.

```py
# Open the excel document using a context manager in 'append' mode.
with pd.ExcelWriter(excelAutoNamed, mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    for excel_file in excel_files:
        print(excel_file)
        # Append Dataframe to Excel File.
        pd.read_excel(excel_file, engine="openpyxl").to_excel(writer, index=False)
        # Append Dataframe with two blank columns to File.
        pd.DataFrame([np.nan, np.nan]).T.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Thank for the idea, but this seems to only work for zip files? I have a path set up of where these excel files are located
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file